# Electron border-less window shows title bar when window is not in focus

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, electron

I've been looking around stack overflow as well as github forums, and haven't found any questions related to this issue. I am making a window using electron, and giving it the property of `frame: false`, which hides both the frame of the window as well as the title bar. However upon bringing the window out of focus the first time after starting the program (i.e. clicking anywhere outside of the window), a title bar suddenly appears, looking strangely glitched when out of focus, and remains on the window until the program is restarted.

my main.js file is written as follows:

```
const electron = require('electron');
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');

let win;

function createWindow(){
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        height: 170,
        width: 520,
        maxHeight: 170,
        maxWidth: 520,
        minHeight: 170,
        minWidth: 520,
        frame: false,
        show: false,
        transparent: true
    });
    win.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        protocol: 'file',
        slashes: true
    }));

    win.on('closed', () => {
        win = null;
    });

    win.once('ready-to-show', () => {
        win.show();
    });
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);
```

[Window's normal appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jV6t5.png)

[Window out of focus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjPLZ.png)

[Window in focus, but after clicking out of focus previously](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxpEb.png)

edit: I am using Windows 10 for this.

Comment: Is it in MacOS?

Comment: it is in Windows.

Comment: I just cloned [electron-quick-start](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start) and added you config to make frameless window. It worked with any issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this bug has been acknowledged and fixed in Electron 1.8.3:

[Windows: Unexpected titlebar for frameless and transparent windows · Issue #11849 · electron/electron · GitHub](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/11849)

[Electron title on frameless with transparency · Issue #12033 · electron/electron · GitHub](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/12033)

Comment: that fixed it for the most part. it still flickers the title bar occasionally so electron may need to touch that up a bit but its not constantly there anymore.